# Fullcalendar, hover effects on day number

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create a hover effect on day numbers using FullCalendar version 3. The effect I'm going for is like this one [here](https://demos.creative-tim.com/fullcalendar?_ga=2.144838964.1691583237.1524465323-525305851.1524465323).

The issue is, in version 3, the data for each day is separated into 2 tables. The first table is the "day" box, while the second table has the information like "day number" and "events".

So i'm trying to figure out if there is a way with css, and if not, then jQuery.  Here is a sample of the first table:

```
<div class="fc-bg">
  <table class="">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is a sample of the second table:

```
<div class="fc-content-skeleton">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2018-04-01">
          <a class="fc-day-number" data-goto="{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2018-04-01&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;day&quot;}">1</a>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2018-04-02">
          <a class="fc-day-number" data-goto="{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2018-04-02&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;day&quot;}">2</a>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2018-04-03">
          <a class="fc-day-number" data-goto="{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2018-04-03&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;day&quot;}">3</a>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2018-04-04">
          <a class="fc-day-number" data-goto="{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2018-04-04&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;day&quot;}">4</a>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2018-04-05">
          <a class="fc-day-number" data-goto="{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2018-04-05&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;day&quot;}">5</a>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2018-04-06">
          <a class="fc-day-number" data-goto="{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2018-04-06&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;day&quot;}">6</a></td>
        <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2018-04-07">
          <a class="fc-day-number" data-goto="{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2018-04-07&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;day&quot;}">7</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS I have tried so far:

```
.fc-day:hover ~ .fc-day-number {
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}
```

The obvious issue is that I need a way to tie to the two table cells together `fc-day` and `fc-day-top` > `fc-day-number`.

I'm wondering if jQuery is the better way to go and if it is, I'm not real strong with it and not sure how to tie them together.

**UPDATE**

So I "Kind Of" got this working using jQuery. After thinking about it some more, the one thing that does tie these cells together is the `data-date` attribute.

However, the highlight affect I want, is kind of laggy and not smooth like CSS. Maybe somebody can help me clean this up or make it more efficient?

```
$('.fc-day').hover(function() {
    var myEm = $(this).attr('data-date');
        $('.fc-day-top[data-date = '+myEm+'] .fc-day-number').css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
  }, function() {
        var myEm = $(this).attr('data-date');
    $('.fc-day-top[data-date = '+myEm+'] .fc-day-number').css({'background-color':'transparent'})
  });
```

**UPDATE 2**

So I got this working and with the help of some of you here in the comments, I changed adding CSS via jQuery to instead adding/removing classes. I also found that the default CSS for FullCalendar has `fc-bg` class set to `z-index` of 1. That causes an issue because the hover effect only works if your mouse is on part of the grid where there is nothing overlaying it.  So I for now have changed the `z-index` to 5 which makes the hover effect work.  The next issue is figuring out how to make links within the calendar remain clickable with this change.  Anywho, here is my code so far:

```
$('.fc-day').hover(function() {
    var myEm = $(this).attr('data-date');
        $('.fc-day-top[data-date = '+myEm+'] .fc-day-number').addClass('on-hover');
  }, function() {
        var myEm = $(this).attr('data-date');
    $('.fc-day-top[data-date = '+myEm+'] .fc-day-number').removeClass('on-hover');
  });
```

**UPDATE 3**

A new development.  When the calendar is changed to another month or different type of view, the jQuery function to create hover effect no longer works unless you refresh the page.  Upon further searching, there is a method that can be called from FullCalendar `viewRender`.  How could I hook my function into this?

```
viewRender: function (element) {

    }
```

Comment: .fc-day:hover .fc-day-number {

Comment: no that doesn't work

Comment: See my answer it provides a cleaner solution

Comment: @RiotAct I sow your update after I post my answer but look at my answer I help you to solve the issue

Comment: @RiotAct See my update... It's realy wird laibary.... ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got this working so I'll just post the answer. Thanks to the other commenters here for giving me some direction. Although their answers didn't get the result I was looking for, it was very helpful.

So I used jQuery to add/remove a class when a cell was hovered, and also had to make a bit of a change to make this work with FullCalendar when a month was changed or the view was changed.  I did this with `viewRender`.  So the hover function had to be included in the FullCalendar jQuery.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: false,
        header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
        right: 'prev,next'
      },
    defaultView: 'month',
        views: {
        month: { // name of view
        columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd', // Mon
        },
    },
        navLinks: true,
    height: 'parent',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',
        viewRender: function (element) {
            $('.fc-day, .fc-day-top').hover(function() {
            var myEm = $(this).attr('data-date');
                $('.fc-day-top[data-date = '+myEm+'] .fc-day-number').addClass('on-hover');
          }, function() {
                var myEm = $(this).attr('data-date');
            $('.fc-day-top[data-date = '+myEm+'] .fc-day-number').removeClass('on-hover');
          });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** This cant be done with CSS alone since `fc-day-number` is not child of `fc-day`.

**Solution:** You can use Jquery for adding a class containing the hover properties on mousein and remove that class on mouseout.

CSS

```
.on-hover {
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.fc-day').on('mousein', function() {
  $('.fc-day-number').addClass('on-hover');
}).on('mouseout', function() {
  $('.fc-day-number').removeClass('on-hover');
});
```

Comment: Hey take a look how version 3 is built in because the number (the day of date)  is not part of all `td` It's in diffrent table

Comment: yes i think my solution is not absolutely correct, but i have given the idea of adding and removing a class

Comment: I did make a slight change based on your answer though and instead of adding and removing css used the addClass and removeClass.

Answer (score 0):

Add event when `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to the day

```
 $('.fc-day.fc-widget-content').mouseenter(function() {
        var date=this.dataset.date;
        var day=$('.fc-day-top.fc-past').filter(function(){return this.dataset.date===date}).children()
        day.addClass('fc-event-hover');
      });

      $('.fc-day.fc-widget-content').mouseleave(function() {
                    var date=this.dataset.date;
        var day=$('.fc-day-top.fc-past').filter(function(){return this.dataset.date===date}).children()
        day.removeClass('fc-event-hover');
      });
```

**CSS:**

```
.fc-event-hover{
 background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}
```

Comment: I hope it will help You right It's really hard to find it because the build it very wird

Comment: Tell me if you need help!

Comment: I am getting errors with this:  Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
var todayDate = moment().startOf('day');

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.fc-basic-view .fc-day-number, .fc-basic-view .fc-week-number {
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 2px;
    min-width:19px;
    text-align: center;
  
}

.fc-week .fc-day-top:hover .fc-day-number{
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 50% ;
    color: #FFFFFF ;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: his target when hover all day not when hover on the number like in the version he attach to the question